# CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling

Tags: compiler-errors, blockchain, solidity, web3js, hardhat

// SPDX-License-Identifier: [`

```
`MIT`
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Record {
    struct Patients {
        string ic;
        string name;
        string phone;
        string gender;
        string dob;
        string height;
        string weight;
        string houseaddr;
        string bloodgroup;
        string allergies;
        string medication;
        string emergencyName;
        string emergencyContact;
        address addr;
        uint date;
    }

    struct Doctors {
        string ic;
        string name;
        string phone;
        string gender;
        string dob;
        string qualification;
        string major;
        address addr;
        uint date;
    }

    struct Appointments {
        address doctoraddr;
        address patientaddr;
        string date;
        string time;
        string prescription;
        string description;
        string diagnosis;
        string status;
        uint creationDate;
    }

    address public owner;
    address[] public patientList;
    address[] public doctorList;
    address[] public appointmentList;

    mapping(address => Patients) patients;
    mapping(address => Doctors) doctors;
    mapping(address => Appointments) appointments;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) isApproved;
    mapping(address => bool) isPatient;
    mapping(address => bool) isDoctor;
    mapping(address => uint) AppointmentPerPatient;

    uint256 public patientCount = 0;
    uint256 public doctorCount = 0;
    uint256 public appointmentCount = 0;
    uint256 public permissionGrantedCount = 0;

    function record() public {
        // Record -> record;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    //Retrieve patient details from user sign up page and store the details into the blockchain
    function setDetails(
        string memory _ic,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _phone,
        string memory _gender,
        string memory _dob,
        string memory _height,
        string memory _weight,
        string memory _houseaddr,
        string memory _bloodgroup,
        string memory _allergies,
        string memory _medication,
        string memory _emergencyName,
        string memory _emergencyContact
    ) public {
        require(!isPatient[msg.sender]);
        Patients storage p = patients[msg.sender];

        p.ic = _ic;
        p.name = _name;
        p.phone = _phone;
        p.gender = _gender;
        p.dob = _dob;
        p.height = _height;
        p.weight = _weight;
        p.houseaddr = _houseaddr;
        p.bloodgroup = _bloodgroup;
        p.allergies = _allergies;
        p.medication = _medication;
        p.emergencyName = _emergencyName;
        p.emergencyContact = _emergencyContact;
        p.addr = msg.sender;
        p.date = block.timestamp;

        patientList.push(msg.sender);
        isPatient[msg.sender] = true;
        isApproved[msg.sender][msg.sender] = true;
        patientCount++;
    }

    //Allows patient to edit their existing record
    function editDetails(
        string memory _ic,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _phone,
        string memory _gender,
        string memory _dob,
        string memory _height,
        string memory _weight,
        string memory _houseaddr,
        string memory _bloodgroup,
        string memory _allergies,
        string memory _medication,
        string memory _emergencyName,
        string memory _emergencyContact
    ) public {
        require(isPatient[msg.sender]);
        Patients storage p = patients[msg.sender];

        p.ic = _ic;
        p.name = _name;
        p.phone = _phone;
        p.gender = _gender;
        p.dob = _dob;
        p.height = _height;
        p.weight = _weight;
        p.houseaddr = _houseaddr;
        p.bloodgroup = _bloodgroup;
        p.allergies = _allergies;
        p.medication = _medication;
        p.emergencyName = _emergencyName;
        p.emergencyContact = _emergencyContact;
        p.addr = msg.sender;
    }

    //Retrieve patient details from doctor registration page and store the details into the blockchain
    function setDoctor(
        string memory _ic,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _phone,
        string memory _gender,
        string memory _dob,
        string memory _qualification,
        string memory _major
    ) public {
        require(!isDoctor[msg.sender]);
        Doctors storage d = doctors[msg.sender];

        d.ic = _ic;
        d.name = _name;
        d.phone = _phone;
        d.gender = _gender;
        d.dob = _dob;
        d.qualification = _qualification;
        d.major = _major;
        d.addr = msg.sender;
        d.date = block.timestamp;

        doctorList.push(msg.sender);
        isDoctor[msg.sender] = true;
        doctorCount++;
    }

    //Allows doctors to edit their existing profile
    function editDoctor(
        string memory _ic,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _phone,
        string memory _gender,
        string memory _dob,
        string memory _qualification,
        string memory _major
    ) public {
        require(isDoctor[msg.sender]);
        Doctors storage d = doctors[msg.sender];

        d.ic = _ic;
        d.name = _name;
        d.phone = _phone;
        d.gender = _gender;
        d.dob = _dob;
        d.qualification = _qualification;
        d.major = _major;
        d.addr = msg.sender;
    }

    //Retrieve appointment details from appointment page and store the details into the blockchain`
    function setAppointment(
        address _addr,
        string memory _date,
        string memory _time,
        string memory _diagnosis,
        string memory _prescription,
        string memory _description,
        string memory _status
    ) public {
        require(isDoctor[msg.sender]);
        Appointments storage a = appointments[_addr];

        a.doctoraddr = msg.sender;
        a.patientaddr = _addr;
        a.date = _date;
        a.time = _time;
        a.diagnosis = _diagnosis;
        a.prescription = _prescription;
        a.description = _description;
        a.status = _status;
        a.creationDate = block.timestamp;

        appointmentList.push(_addr);
        appointmentCount++;
        AppointmentPerPatient[_addr]++;
    }

    //Retrieve appointment details from appointment page and store the details into the blockchain
    function updateAppointment(
        address _addr,
        string memory _date,
        string memory _time,
        string memory _diagnosis,
        string memory _prescription,
        string memory _description,
        string memory _status
    ) public {
        require(isDoctor[msg.sender]);
        Appointments storage a = appointments[_addr];

        a.doctoraddr = msg.sender;
        a.patientaddr = _addr;
        a.date = _date;`your text`
        a.time = _time;
        a.diagnosis = _diagnosis;
        a.prescription = _prescription;
        a.description = _descriptio`your text`n;
        a.status = _status;
    }

    //Owner of the record must give permission to doctor only they are allowed to view records
    function givePermission(address _address) public returns`
```

$ /mnt/c/Codeeater/node_modules/.bin/hardhat run scripts/major_project.js
CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling with `--via-ir` (cli) or the equivalent `viaIR: true` (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables. When compiling inline assembly: Variable dataEnd is 1 slot(s) too deep inside the stack. Stack too deep. Try compiling with `--via-ir` (cli) or the equivalent `viaIR: true` (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables.

**I am getting these error while compiling the above code **``](https://stackoverflow.com)
`

Comment: If you have an issue with my answer, please add it as comment to my answer. Please don't edit the answer. Answers and comments are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because the EVM has a limitation of 16 variables in a function. If it tries to access a variable in slot16 or later (0-indexed), you'll get this error.

You have issues because of functions like: `setDetails` and `editDetails`.

To fix this error, you can send a `struct` instead of individual variables, like:

```
function setDetails(Patients memory patient) {
    require(!isPatient[msg.sender]);

    patients[msg.sender] = patient;
    patients[msg.sender].addr = msg.sender;
    patients[msg.sender].date = block.timestamp;

    patientList.push(msg.sender);
    isPatient[msg.sender] = true;
    isApproved[msg.sender][msg.sender] = true;
    patientCount++;
}
```

You'll need to send some dummy values for `addr` and `date` when you send the argument `patient` to the function. Or create another `struct` without `date` and `addr`, so that you can accept the function argument.

You can then do the same for `editDetails`.

---

If you try to send the below to `setDetails`

```
(
  "123456789",
  "John Doe",
  "123-456-7890",
  "Male",
  "01/01/1990",
  "6 feet",
  "180 lbs",
  "123 Main St",
  "O+",
  "None",
  "Prescription Meds",
  "Emergency Contact",
  "123-456-7890"
)
```

This will return an error because there are 15 parameters in your struct. You need to pass dummy values for `date` and `addr` to match.

Comment: (
  "123456789",
  "John Doe",
  "123-456-7890",
  "Male",
  "01/01/1990",
  "6 feet",
  "180 lbs",
  "123 Main St",
  "O+",
  "None",
  "Prescription Meds",
  "Emergency Contact",
  "123-456-7890",
  address(0),
  0
)
after adding dummy value for date and addr I'm still getting error

Comment: @Thameshchandravanshi Can you add the error you are getting here as a comment?

Comment: transact to Record.setDetails errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":15}, value={"types":["tuple(string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,address,uint256)"],"values":["123456789","John Doe","123-456-7890","Male","01/01/1990","6 feet","180 lbs","123 Main St","O+","None","Prescription Meds","Emergency Contact","123-456-7890","address(0)","0 )"]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)